# How i cant put the tick or cross sign if front of input field in forms after validate

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I want to add this sign in front of input field to tell that it is correct or not. in javascript**

[image]

Comment: Do you have any code to share?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you can do something what [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) already provides, called `input-addons`:

```css
body {padding: 50px;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
<div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-2">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need, you can also add `text-warning` class to get the same colour effect.

**Preview:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add ::after pseudo element to the input box which contains a tick image or a cross image (handled by classes ) and on validation simply display the corresponding image.
For more reference see documentation of after/before pseudo elements.

Comment: Which way is better to to show image of tick or cross....
 ::after pseudo element or use the img tag <img> dynamically?